# I am getting an error when i parse the json string which is response

Tags: android, json

```
private String getHttpPost(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    //  Log.d("Entire httppost::", " " + httpPost);
     //httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
      //  httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
    Log.e("server Response", "json format "+is);
     } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return str.toString();
     try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
            //Log.d("Json array as response", " " + sb);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //paring data
     if (result != null) {
        try{
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        Log.d("Json array as response", " " + jArray);

        for(int a=0; a<jArray.length(); a++){
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(a);

                rid = json_data.optString("id").toString();  
                responcerecent = json_data.optString("response").toString();
               Log.d("Id",""+ rid);
                Log.d("Response", " "+ responcerecent);
                dbHelper.updateSyncStatus(rid, responcerecent);
        }



        }catch(JSONException e1){
             e1.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ParseException e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        //dbHelper.delete_classdata();
        //Log.d("All data relatedclass table deleted", "dbHelper.delete_classdata()");  
    }  

     else {
        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }


    return sb.toString();
   }
```

My logcat

```
08-20 13:41:32.670: D/Json array as response(11758):  [{"response":"1","id":"3"}]
08-20 13:41:32.670: D/Id(11758): 3
08-20 13:41:32.670: D/Response(11758):  1
08-20 13:41:32.670: W/dalvikvm(11758): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41561ba8)
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10188
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758): Process: com.edbeans.attendance:my_process, PID: 11758
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758):    at com.edbeans.attendance.MyService.getHttpPost(MyService.java:325)
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758):    at com.edbeans.attendance.MyService.access$0(MyService.java:272)
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758):    at com.edbeans.attendance.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:207)
08-20 13:41:32.670: E/AndroidRuntime(11758):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I am getting proper response but it not get parse and add to respective table. What is the error i cant get it. can anyone check my code is correct or not. This method is write in service class to send the data on background thread and fetch the response from server. Hi if i remove dbHelper.updateSyncStatus(rid, responcerecent); line then its properly work without ANR but i want to add that response to table in db.. so how can I solve this

Comment: what is your line 325?

Comment: which one line? from code? or logcat

Comment: from the code. I'm guessing is was never initialized or got a null value

Comment: Use AsyncTask, and parse json in onPostExecute, then you can find out the root cause.

Comment: Probably `dbHelper ` is `null`

Comment: StringBuilder I already declare on start.. M not getting their is no such line 325

Comment: @ArunShankar can u please show me where and how i canuse yhis code in asynk task.

Comment: check your result what you getting from server and then 
jArray = new JSONArray(result); statement

Comment: try log sb.toString(), check if its null, if not it will be a json parsing error,

Comment: @Pavan just checked it gives me RESULT:  [{"id":"3","response":"1"}]

Comment: @ArunShankar Thanks. But i already tried same thing and it give me same error..

Comment: **dbHelper.updateSyncStatus(rid, responcerecent);** have you checked whether that line is throwing exception or not?

Comment: @Asmi check your dbHelper object  this is the case may cause you null pointer

Comment: @ShadowDroid  comment out that dbhelper line still I got same error. so i think its not dbhelper line problem.

Comment: @Pavan comment out that dbhelper line still I got same error. so i think its not dbhelper line problem.

Comment: @Asmi you can do line by debugging for this code so you can get where is the mistake

Comment: @Pavan Ok sure vl try..

Comment: @Pavan Hi if i remove dbhelperline then its properly work without ANR but i want to add that response to table in db.. so how can I solve this

Comment: @ArunShankar Hi if i remove dbhelperline then its properly work without ANR but i want to add that response to table in db.. so how can I solve this

Comment: can u post your json output

Comment: also post the updateSyncStatus method from dbhelper

Comment: Hello Thank u so much your valuable response.. I debug line by line and  found that my dbhelper initialization is again needed. Because Its scope is limited. So my problem is solved...:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP client you are using is deprecated and shouldn't be used. I recommend that you use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp) instead as that is much easier to use and more stable.

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion but i got response but it gets stop after that and show ANR block on device

Comment: I know, that is why you should use OkHttp instead. It has a very nice async API that makes the network call on a background thread.